# Not getting the actual output for the following code:

Tags: java, netbeans

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main {

       Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
       int n = 0, tn = 0, time = 0;int sum=0;
       int t = input.nextInt(); //no. of test cases
       for (int i =0; i<t; i++)
       {  
          n = input.nextInt();//no. of timings           
          for (int j = 0; j<n; j++)
           {   
               tn = input.nextInt(); //individual time

               sum=0;
               sum+=tn;
               sum*=2;
           }
          System.out.println(t+". "+sum);
        }

    }
}
```

[My output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31gj5.png)

[output I am supposed to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPYx4.png)

Can anyone tell me where I went wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) You are setting every time `sum=0` while taking new input so you are losing the previous values hence last time

```
sum=30
sum= 30*2 = 60
```

so reset the `sum=0` when you are done with your first case input

2.) You need to do the multiplication after you add-up all the values so simply do the multiplication when you have the `sum` of all `individual time` values

```
for (int i = 0; i < t; i++) {
    n = input.nextInt();// no. of timings
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        tn = input.nextInt(); // individual time
        // add all values first
        sum += tn;
    }
    // multiply the total of values with 2
    System.out.println(i + ". " + (sum * 2));

    // now set sum=0 for next case
    sum = 0;
}
```

Test case Output :

```
2
3
10
20
30
2. 120 // output of first case
2
100
50
2. 300 // output of second case
```

Comment: one more thing...can u make an edit for System.out.println(i + ". " + (sum * 2)); it should be 'i' instead of 't' so we get the correct index no. in output..sorry I wrote it wrong in my code earlier